# Error message: An instance of the game is already running

Tags: age-of-empires-online

When I open the launcher for Age of Empires Online, it shows the error message:

> An instance of the game is already running.

I already rebooted my computer but the message is appearing again.

Does anybody know how to fix this error?

Comment: Browse to your game installation directory. Try right click on the AOEOnline.exe executable and then click on Run as Administrator.

Answer (score -1):

i think you just need to go to task manager and shutdown the process of Age of Empires Online, cause it says it's already running.If that's out of the question, try reinstalling it and otherwise contact people from Age of Empires Online if you are so desperate to play the game.